# I can't handle php mysql login page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a change password for users. But I cant manage to do it. Whatever I tried, it returns me the problem alert I wrote. Can anyone suggest anything? I am trying to fix it for hours.

The below is my form code;

```
                <form action="change_s_pwd.php" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="bb">
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        Kullanıcı Adı : 
                                        <div class="controls">

                                            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your Login ID" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="4"/>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <p>Secure ID :                                      </p>
                                        <div class="controls">

<input type="text" name="sec_id"  class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Your Secure ID" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        Password :
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="input-xlarge" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6" placeholder="Your new passowrd">
                                     </div>
                                                        </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        Confirm password :
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirmfield" id="confirmfield" class="input-xlarge" data-rule-equalto="#pass" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm Your new passowrd">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls"></div>
                                    </div>
                </div>                  <div class="form-actions">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

And the below is the submit code;

```
<?php
include 'index.php';
include '../include/db_conn.php';
if (isset($_POST['sec_id']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_SESSION['user_data'])) {
    $sec_id       = rtrim($_POST['sec_id']);
    $pass         = rtrim($_POST['pass']);
    $user_id_auth = $_SESSION['user_data'];
    $sql          = "SELECT * FROM login_auth WHERE sec_id='$sec_id'";
    $result       = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count        = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1) {
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE login SET pass='$pass' WHERE user='$user_id_auth'");
        echo "<html><head><script>alert(Password Changed Succesfully ');</script></head></html>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
    } else {
        echo "<html><head><script>alert('There has been a problem while changing password');</script></head></html>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<html><head><script>alert('There has been a problem while changing password');</script></head></html>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
}
?>
<center>
<img src="loading.gif">
</center>
```

I will be so glad if you guys can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you write `session_start()` at the top of your page??

Comment: *Which* problem alert?

Comment: you need `session_start()`.

Comment: So write and check!!

Comment: If you are using `$_SESSION` you MUST open the session connection on the top of the page.

Comment: @RowlandShaw  `alert('There has been a problem while changing password');`

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error($con)` after `mysqli_query($con, $sql)`. Does it return an error ?

Comment: Where do you insert the datas ?

Comment: I added `session_start()` but it still gives me the same alert

Comment: I don't know why there are 2 `else`. Try to edit your if like `if ($count == 1)` then `else if ($count > 1)` to see the error. If there are many results, one or 0. If there are 2 `else` with nothing, your program will never reach the second `else`

Comment: @Hearner the last else is the first ifs' in line 4.

Comment: Oh my bad, I haven't seen

Comment: You've two places that error could return - try changing one so that you can find out which conidiotn is failing

Answer (score 0):

you are making the check on the $count variable in which it contains the number of rows that returns from the $result (result set)and it maybe equal to 0 if the mysqli_query function return no result (empty query result ...) so you must check first the result set ($result) then get the $count ... in this case you will be sure if the mysqli_query returns a result or not .. like the below code ... :

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $sql          = "SELECT * FROM login_auth WHERE sec_id='$sec_id'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
```

also do not write html code as a string with php ... this will lead to many errors and it will be hard for you to debug the problem ... use the header function in php or the redirect  to redirect to the page you want in the case you want ...